# Consequences of UP equals NP

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, conditional-results, unique-solution

EDIT at 2011/02/08:
After some references finding and reading, I decided to separate the original question into two separate ones. Here's the part concerning UP vs NP, for the syntactic and semantic classes part please see [Benefits for syntactic and semantic classes](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/4792/1800).

---

$\mathsf{UP}$ (the unambiguous polynomial time, see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UP_(complexity)) and [the zoo](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo:U#up) for references) is defined as languages decided by $\mathsf{NP}$-machines with an additional constrain that

- There is at most one accepting computation path on any input.

The precise relations between $\mathsf{P}$ vs $\mathsf{UP}$ and $\mathsf{UP}$ vs $\mathsf{NP}$ are still open. We know that worst-case one-way functions exist if and only if $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{UP}$, and there are oracles relative to all possibilities of the inclusions $\mathsf{P} \subseteq \mathsf{UP} \subseteq \mathsf{NP}$.

I'm interested in why $\mathsf{UP}$ vs $\mathsf{NP}$ is an important question. People tend to believe (at least [in](http://ccc.cs.uni-duesseldorf.de/~rothe/PDF/26197.pdf) [literature](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~lane/=companion/isolation.pdf)) that these two classes are different, and my problem is:

> If $\mathsf{UP} = \mathsf{NP}$, are there any "bad" consequences happened?

There is a related post on [complexity blog](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2003/12/does-npup.html) in 2003. And if my understanding is correct, [the result](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.32.8999&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Hemaspaandra, Naik, Ogiwara and Selman shows that if

- There is an $\mathsf{NP}$ language $L$ such that for each satisfiable formula $\phi$ there is a *unique* satisfying assignment $x$ with $(\phi,x)$ in $L$,

then the polynomial hierarchy collapses to the second level. No such implication is known if $\mathsf{UP} = \mathsf{NP}$ holds.

Comment: (1) It is easy to see (almost by definition) that UP and BPP have complete problems if “problems” can refer to promise problems.  They are not known to have complete _languages_.  (2) I do not know the precise definition of syntactic classes.  Is PH syntactic?  It does not have a complete problem (even with promise) unless the polynomial hierarchy collapses.  (3) I do not know your usage of the notation “PromiseUP.”  If NP means the class of _languages_ recognized by an NP machine and PromiseUP means the class of _promise problems_ recognized by a UP machine, then clearly they cannot be equal.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Thank you for the questions. (1) By problems I do mean *languages*, it's my fault that I do not write this clearly. (2) We define syntactic classes as having [leaf language characterizations](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/761/1800) on poly-time machines. **PH** is special, since no poly-time leaf language characterization is known, where natural complete languages are guaranteed; but **PH** do have a *logspace* leaf language characterization. (more)

Comment: (cont.) (3) Maybe the use of **PromiseUP** is not correct. Here by **PromiseUP** I mean a class of *languages*, such that for yes instances the machine has a unique accepting path, and for no instances the machine have zero or at least two accepting paths.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  As for (3), from a cursory look at the paper by Hemaspaandra, Naik, Ogihara and Selman, I cannot find a way to state the result in terms of decision problems.  BTW, the link to the paper is broken.  Here is a [link to the journal version](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0097539794268315).

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Is the following reasoning correct: If **NP** = **PromiseUP**, then all problems in **NP** reduce to USAT, which is the problem containing all formulas with a unique assignment. Then, given a formula as input, we can output a unique satisfying assignment in **NP** by guessing, which satisfies the requirement of the paper [HNOS96].

Comment: First, the “class of languages, such that for yes instances the machine has a unique accepting path, and for no instances the machine have zero or at least two accepting paths” is called US.  See [my answer to another question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/verifying-unique-solutions-of-sat/1641#1641).  (more)

Comment: (cont’d)  Second, I cannot see how the condition NP=US implies Hypothesis 1.1 in [HNOS96].  What I cannot understand is that your function (required for Hypothesis 1.1) seems to be changing the formula, but it is not allowed.  But I must be missing something simple because the introduction of [HNOS96] states that NP=coNP “clearly” implies Hypothesis 1.1 and I cannot see the reason for this either.

Comment: Just to make sure, PromiseUP is completely different from what you described.  As I wrote, PromiseUP is the promise-problem version of UP; that is, it is the class of promise problems having a nondeterministic polynomial-time Turing machine M such that for yes-instances M has exactly one accepting path and for no-instances M _does not have_ accepting paths.  Although I believe that PromiseUP is the traditional name for this class, some people (including me) write this class simply as UP.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Since **US** [contains](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo:U#us) **coNP**, if **NP** = **coNP** then the above reasoning may work (we only use the condition that **NP** $\subseteq$ **US**). Also, the function here is the NP-machine which guesses the assignments, and the value of the function on x is the set of outputs from accepting paths of the machine. (See defn 2.2 in [HNOS96].) So as the machine does not depend on the input x, the function does not depend on the input formula.

Comment: You are right about the definitions of **PromiseUP** and **US**. I'll correct them in the next revision, maybe together with something else, since constantly revise the same problem will disturb other users in TCS SE.

Comment: Well, your explanation of how NP=US implies Hypothesis 1.1 does not resolve my concern (I know the definition of NPSV).  I cannot see how to output a satisfying assignment for the _given_ formula instead of outputting some different formula with a unique satisfying assignment.  But I will think a little more about it.  (Also I guess that this is kind of off topic here.)

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito: One can prove $NP=coNP$ implies Hyp. 1.1 directly, without recourse to $US$: Let $M$ be a machine for the $coNP$ language consisting of pairs $(\varphi,w)$ such that $w$ is the lex. least satisfying assignment for $\varphi$. The following $NPSV$ machine outputs satisfying assignments: on input $\varphi$, nondet. guess a witness $w$; apply $M(\varphi,w)$ and output $w$ only on accepting paths of $M$. I believe that if Hsien-Chih's argument worked, the same argument, combined iwth the HNOS result, would show that $NP=UP$ implies $PH$ collapses, which is not known.

Comment: @Joshua: You are right, and I found the mistake in my reasoning, which is precisely what Tsuyoshi has said. I am still reading some related material, hope that after a more complete understanding to the problem I can revise the question properly. Thank you for the proof!

Comment: @Tayfun: sorry for asking, what is a C.C.? complexity class?

Comment: @Tayfun: Since P $\subseteq$ UP and coUP, any complexity class separated from P works? I guess you're interested in a somewhat larger class?

Answer (score 4):

It is known that $\mathsf{UP= NP}$ implies $\mathsf{SpanP = \#P}$ since Kobler, Schoning, and Toran proved that $\mathsf{UP= NP}$ if and only if $\mathsf{SpanP = \#P}$. It is easy to see that $\mathsf {\#P}$ is contained in $\mathsf {SpanP}$.

A function $f : Σ^* →\mathbb N$ is in $\mathsf{SpanP}$ if there is an $\mathsf {NP}$ Turing machine transducer $M$ such that for all $x$, $f(x)$ is the number of distinct outputs of $M$ on input $x$.

J. Kobler, U. Schoning, and J. Toran. [On counting and approximation](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00276023), Acta Informatica,
26:363-379, 1989.

Comment: This answer (http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/20645/495) also works here since if $UP = NP$ then the disjoint $NP$-pairs conjecture is false.